# FontAwesome icons display as small rectangle if class fa is missing

Tags: css, font-awesome

In my website I am using font-awesome 4.2.0, but there is a strange problem: Lets say I want to get a right caret, I have to do

```
<span class="fa fa-caret-right">whatever</span>
```

If I change it to

```
<span class="fa-caret-right">whatever</span>
```

a small rectangle will display instead of the right caret icon. I test it with other website using FA4, the "fa" class is not necessary. This bothers me because the "fa" class sets the `font-family` to "fontawesome" for the whole span, overriding my own `font-family` for the span.

Here is a little background that might be informational: I build my website with joomla and use RocketTheme Corvus template, which integrates Font-awesome 3.0(It seems FA has been customized in this template. To use FA icons, instead of `fa-icontype`, one has to use `icon-icontype`) .  I followed exactly the instructions in this post http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/joomla-general-questions/225736-updating-your-template-from-font-awesome-3-to-4?start=0#1112560 to upgrade to FA4, only to find the FA icons won't show. And there are several errors on the page, two of them are

```
http://localhost/xrsand/libraries/gantry/assets/jui/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://localhost/xrsand/libraries/gantry/assets/jui/fonts/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

In contrast to step3 in the post, which says I need to create a font-awesome4 folder, these two errors suggest that the system fail to load a file whose path include a `font-awesome` folder without "4". So I try changing the folder's name from "font-awesome4" to "font-awesome", and the FA icons are working... except that I have to add class "fa". I'm not sure if the problem is related to how I upgrade the version and the fact that I change the folder's name, I put it here just for your information.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a workaround myself.

```
[class^="fa-"]:before, [class*=" fa-"]:before{font-family:fontawesome}
```

The above CSS will make sure the pseudo :before content, where the FA icons actually live, gets font-family set to fontawesome. With this I can remove 'fa' class. It seems to me that class 'fa' exists only to set the font-family to fontawesome(There are many other CSS rules associated with it, but it seems to me only the font-family matters)

If anyone think this may cause some potential problem, please let me know.

By the way, I test it on font-awesome's official website, and surprisingly, if I remove class 'fa', the icon will reduce to an ugly rectangle. This is kind of uneasy for me, they make class 'fa' mandate for a reason, don't they?